# How to find size of a data type in pl/sql (oracle 9i)?

Tags: sql, oracle9i

I want to find the size of any data type in pl/sql,for eg
DECLARE
x boolean;

I want to find size of like X,is there any function like (sizeof() in C) or any how i can find it.Please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Look up vsize() - I believe it exists for some versions of Oracle (10g and above judging from Google search), though whether it exists for Oracle 9 I do not know.